# Notepad ++ How to create a Macro to Bookmark certain lines based on 5 different values

Tags: macros, notepad++, bookmarks

I am wondering if it is possible to use Notepad ++ to create a macro that I can use to find the following values of "SUPP1, SUPP2, SUPP3, SUPP4, WAVSL" and bookmark the lines they are present on.

I have roughly 90 files to sift through and locate records within these files, copying them to another file. I know I can do this manually, but any time that can be saved here is appreciated. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks,

Brandon

Comment: So you know what to search for, go and bookmark - CTRL+F, "Mark" tab, check *Bookmark line* and type `SUPP1, SUPP2, SUPP3, SUPP4, WAVSL` into the search field. And hit *Mark All*. If you provide more specific details, there might be a better solution. What do you bookmark them for?

Comment: Hi - I'm trying to identify records where the values noted above exist, bookmark those lines with the macro and then I can copy the bookmarks with a short-cut to another file. Open the next file, run the macro to find and bookmark where the values above exist and bookmark them, and then I can use the short-cut again to copy them to the other file. I'm not sure if this is an option or not. I've tried the record feature thus far, but it doesn't seem to record bookmarking as an action taken.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer here. Part of the issue was the version on the server for Notepad++ was around 5.6.9 before they had the "Mark All" feature and it was supported for scripting in macros. I found a newer version on another server that is around 6.8 or 6.9 and it worked recording the macro there for usage.

Thanks,

Brandon

Comment: I found it through some general digging on the topic elsewhere. Link below to thread...  https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/59fa8ac6/#dced